# for loop in react

Tags: javascript, loops, reactjs, for-loop, ecmascript-6

I got this function working to get some gym classes from a .json file.

```
    filtrarClase(dia, hora) {
    let data = this.state.data
    return data.filter(clase => {
        if ((clase.dia === dia) && (clase.horaclase === hora)) {
            return clase.actividad
        } else { 
            return false
        }
    })
    .map((clase,i) => {
        return (
            <li key={i} className={clase.estilo}>{clase.actividad}
                <p className="duracion">{clase.duracion}</p>
                <p className="sala">{clase.hoy} {clase.sala}</p>
            </li>
        )
    })        
}
```

it's ok, just passing it some "day and hour"  will return right classes. 
But then I can't find a way to loop over this function... and only be able to do  this ****

```
<div className="horario-container">                 
                <ul className="horario-hora">{horas[0]}</ul>
                <ul className="horario-item">{this.filtrarClase(1, horas[0])}</ul>
                <ul className="horario-item">{this.filtrarClase(2, horas[0])}</ul>
                <ul className="horario-item">{this.filtrarClase(3, horas[0])}</ul>
                <ul className="horario-item">{this.filtrarClase(4, horas[0])}</ul>
                <ul className="horario-item">{this.filtrarClase(5, horas[0])}</ul>
                <ul className="horario-item">{this.filtrarClase(6, horas[0])}</ul>                   
            </div>
```

Over and over again... 17 times..

```
            <div className="horario-container">                 
                <ul className="horario-hora">{horas[1]}</ul>
                <ul className="horario-item">{this.filtrarClase(1, horas[16])}</ul>
                <ul className="horario-item">{this.filtrarClase(2, horas[16])}</ul>
                <ul className="horario-item">{this.filtrarClase(3, horas[16])}</ul>
                <ul className="horario-item">{this.filtrarClase(4, horas[16])}</ul>
                <ul className="horario-item">{this.filtrarClase(5, horas[16])}</ul>
                <ul className="horario-item">{this.filtrarClase(6, horas[16])}</ul>                   
            </div>
```

I'm sure you can point me on the right way with a "for" or "forEach", or hope so!
I tried this:

```
    actualizarLista(dia){
    const horas = ['07:30','08:15','08:30','09:30','10:30','15:00','15:15','15:30','17:30','18:00','18:15','18:30','19:00','19:30','20:00','20:30','21:30']
    for (let i=0; i<horas.length;i++){
        return <ul className="horario-item">{this.filtrarClase(dia, horas[i])}</ul>
    }

}

render() {
    let dias = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
    for (let i=0; i<dias.length;i++){
        this.actualizarLista(i)
    }
    return (
        <div className="App">
            <div className="horario-container">
                <div className="horario-list">{dias}</div> .........
```

I tried a for loop but only returns 1 item, so I'm doing something wrong for sure. Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you explain more? and show the loop you are using .

Comment: No, it's working, but I think is not the best practice so I'm asking to know to do it in the right way.

Comment: Sure, `    render() {
        console.log('DATA: ', data)
        const horas = ['07:30','08:15','08:30','09:30','10:30','15:00','15:15','15:30','17:30','18:00','18:15','18:30','19:00','19:30','20:00','20:30','21:30']
        for (let i=0; i<horas.length; i++{
             return <ul>{this.filtrarClases(i, horas[i])</ul>
}

`** "UPDATING QUESTION...**

Comment: @AdolfoOnrubia basically you want to iterate the horas array and create that `<div><ul>.....</ul></div>` dynamically instead of writing all those again and again correct ?

Comment: @MayankShukla exactly, hope you can help me "again"!!! :):)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Reason is, for loop is used to iterate the array it will never return anything, if you want to return something then use `map`.

Write it like this:

```
actualizarLista(dia){
    const horas = ['07:30','08:15','08:30','09:30','10:30','15:00','15:15','15:30','17:30','18:00','18:15','18:30','19:00','19:30','20:00','20:30','21:30']
    return horas.map((el, i) => {
        return <ul className="horario-item">{this.filtrarClase(dia, el)}</ul>
    })
}

render() {
    let dias = [1,2,3,4,5,6];
    let uiItems = dias.map(i => {
        return  <div className="horario-container" key={i}>
                    {this.actualizarLista(i)}
                </div>            
    })       

    return (
        <div className="App">
            {uiItems}
        </div>  
    )      
}
```

**Suggestion:** horas array is constant so i will suggest you to define it once outside of the class.